# MySQL Foreign Key inside Transaction violated

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, foreign-keys

I have read through the MySQL docs and can't seem to find a solution to this issue. Other StackOverFlow questions don't solve my issue.

I have a MySQL database with 3 tables in the scope of this issue. `appointments`,`services`, and `appointment_services`, where `appointments` and `services` have a many-to-many relationship linked through `appointment_services`.

```
CREATE TABLE `appointment_services` (
  `appointmentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `serviceid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `appointment_fk_idx` (`appointmentid`),
  KEY `service_fk` (`serviceid`),
  CONSTRAINT `appointment_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`appointmentid`) REFERENCES `appointments` (`appointmentid`),
  CONSTRAINT `service_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`serviceid`) REFERENCES `services` (`serviceid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `appointments` (
   `appointmentid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `date` date NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`appointmentid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```
CREATE TABLE `services` (
   `serviceid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   `description` mediumtext,
   `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `session_duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`serviceid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

`services` already has multiple rows, including one with `serviceid = 1`.

When I try the following query using a transaction, I get an error indicating I am violating the foreign key constraint in `appointment_services`:

```
13:19:18    INSERT INTO `appointment_services` (appointmentid, serviceid) VALUES (1,1)  Error Code: 1216. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails  0.234 sec
```

```
BEGIN WORK;
INSERT INTO `appointments`
(appointmentid, date) VALUES (1, 2020/01/04);

INSERT INTO `appointment_services`
(appointmentid, serviceid) VALUES (1,1);
COMMIT;
```

I have come across solutions stating that I should set constraints to deffered, however, this is not supported in MySQL.

Comment: Rather than invent your own schema syntax can you show us a simple `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for all 3 tables

Comment: Also, ALWAYS show us the Full Error Message, If you summarise it you will amost definitely leave out the bit someone would consider the most important bit

Comment: The published code works as coded without error which means either your data is not what you think it is or the error comes from elsewhere possibly a trigger.

Comment: @P.Salmon I dont think it does, not as it is published at least

Answer (score 0):

I think your first query here failed as you have the date in the wrong format.

First it needs to be in quotes and second the format must be `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
BEGIN WORK;
INSERT INTO `appointments`
(`appointmentid`, `date`) VALUES (1, '2020-04-01');

INSERT INTO `appointment_services`
(`appointmentid`, `serviceid`) VALUES (1,1);
COMMIT;
```

> PS: I assumed the date was supposed to be the 1st of April 2020 rather than the 4th of January 2020 :)